# Sobolev Spaces with different measures

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

Consider $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ the standard Sobolev space of functions $f\in L^2$ such that the weak derivative of $f$ is also in $L^2$.

Now, my question is the following: if instead of considering the usual Lebesgue measure you endow $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ with, for instance, the following measure $d\mu=e^{-|x|}dx$, would usual Sobolev embeddings still hold? I am particularly interested in, for example, the embedding $H^1\hookrightarrow L^\infty$ (which is a basic result in the one-dimensional case for the Lebesgue measure).

Can someone recommend me some references to learn a little bit about this kind of questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are usually called *weighted Sobolev spaces*, in the sense that you let $d\mu(x)=w(x)\,dx$ for some function $w:\Omega\to [0,+\infty)$ and then call the resulting space 'weighted Sobolev space with respect to the weight $w$'.

For general weights $w$ these spaces are pathological (they may not even include all smooth compactly supported functions...) so you need to add a few requirements to get reasonable spaces. For instance a good class of weights is that of [Muckenhoupt weights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muckenhoupt_weights) - in this case you can show that the usual embedding theorems hold, see e.g. [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233080732_The_local_regularity_of_degenerate_elliptic_equations).

An even more general setting is defining Sobolev spaces over arbitrary metric measure spaces and if you require a 'regularity' condition on the measure which introduces a concept of dimension, you can again obtain embedding theorems (see [here](https://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/OriginalPublications/Hajlasz-Sobolev-PotAnal-5-1996-403-415.pdf)).